# basic Activity starting

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm having some problems here with basic Activity starting

I've tried to use the method below:

```
private void startAC() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, WordSendingActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And while debugging I got some "Source not found" errors which claim that the source attachment does not contain the source for the file: Instrumentation.class, InvocationTargetException.class, Binder.class (in this order)

I got these different class names by trying Run->Step Return

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to preform a basic activity start, how would you do it better?

took me hours to give up my pride and come here :)

I hope my question is clear enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be attempting to "Step Return" into built-in classes. Android classes don't have sources available for debugging. They are binary-only classes in the respective android.jar.

The code for starting the activity looks fine. Are you sure you added WordSendingActivity to the AndroidManifest.xml ?